# R Count number of sign switches for adjacent vector elements

Tags: r, vector

Consider this vector:

```
-3
4
5
-2
4
-5
6
-1
-1
-1
-8
7
```

What is a simple way in R(e.g. without ugly loops) for counting how many "sign switches" are present for adjacent elements?

In this example we would have 7 switches:

```
-3 to 4
5 to -2 
-2 to 4
4 to -5
-5 to 6
6 to -1
-8 to 7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function that does the trick:

```
# Given a numeric array x, this returns the number of sign changes
nSignChanges <- function(x) {
    signs <- sign(x)
    sum(signs[-1] != signs[-length(x)])
}

a <- c(-3, 4, 5, -2, 4, -5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -8, 7)
nSignChanges(a)
```

Comment: Way faster than rle, and instead of running sign over the vector twice, a quick `x<-sign(x)` could be added.

Comment: @Thell I've incorporated your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite function to the rescue:

`rle(sign(your_vector))`

Example, where I assume you have no zeroes:

```
foo<- sample(-5:5,30,rep=TRUE)

foo<-foo[foo!=0]
rle(sign(foo))
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:13] 3 1 2 1 8 5 1 1 1 1 ...
  values : num [1:13] -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 ...
```

EDIT: I concede quality to Trimble:

for a vector 1e6 long, `microbenchmark` returns

```
Unit: milliseconds
               expr       min        lq    median        uq
 nSignChanges(sfoo)  62.64967  68.94004  70.77263  73.27103
 rSignChanges(sfoo) 128.79518 131.19843 137.15204 137.82534
       max neval
  78.51457    10
 141.93182    10
```

Comment: +1 for `sign`, I was trying to make a custom one to use with `rle` and that is nice

Comment: Doesn't that give an answer that is too large by one? So something like `length(rle(sign(your_vector))[[1]])-1` instead?

Comment: @JTT  I think you're right -- I just whacked that answer out w/o comparing the length to the number of changes.